# The redundant `_from` parameter in the `transferFrom` function of an ERC721

Tags: erc-721, function

The Non-Fungible Token Standard (described in [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)) specifies, among other things, the signature of the `transferFrom()` function: `function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;`

Besides, it says that the function "throws if `_from` is not the current owner" of `_tokenId`.

Now, **why** is the `_from` argument required, at all, if it is easily deducible from `_tokenId` (by passing it to the `ownerOf()` function)?
Passing `_from` seems redundant, and the the internal comparison of the argument to the "actual" owner of `_tokenId` - wasteful.

Why not just check whether the `transferFrom()` caller has been approved by the `ownerOf(_tokenId)` to transfer either the `_tokenId` itself (via `approve()`) - or all of the owner's NFTs from the collection (via `setApprovalForAll()`)?

If the caller isn't approved to transfer the NFT, it doesn't matter whether `msg.sender == _ownerOf(_tokenId)`. And if they are approved, then, what is the added value of forcing the caller to also pass the `_from` argument (which can be obtained by simply calling `ownerOf(_tokenId)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great observation on the `_from` parameter! I never noticed this before.

Here are the two key reasons for its inclusion in the `transferFrom()` function in ERC-721:

As you know, **ERC-721** is strongly inspired by **ERC-20**, `_from` parameter is included in both standards for the following reasons:

- Simplifying things for developers by sharing a similar design across both standards, making them easier to use and understand.
- Ensuring consistency across token standards: With the _from parameter in ERC-721, developers can more easily work with various token types, as they share the same signature (**0x23b872dd**): `bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) == 0x23b872dd`

In summary, the `_from` parameter in ERC-721 maintains consistency with other token standards like ERC-20 and simplifies working with diverse tokens for developers.

It was mentioned previously that including the `_from` parameter could save gas by avoiding using `ownerOf(uint256 tokenId)`. However, this function is used anyway on `transferFrom` in OpenZeppelin implementation:

```
function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
    address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
    return (spender == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender) || getApproved(tokenId) == spender);
}
```

Considering this, I don't see any benefits in terms of gas savings by including `_from` parameter in `transferFrom()`.

*EDIT:*

Here is an [Answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126708/why-erc721-does-not-have-direct-transfer-function) from the lead author of ERC-721, which provides additional insight into the reasoning behind this design choice:

> "We did not include a transfer function because it may be ambiguous
> whether you mean to transfer something that you are the owner of
> versus something you are authorized to get.
>
> The current owner must always be specified, because of security
> reasons (specifically, front-running). This is why transferFrom is the
> closest to the wire you can get."

Here's a simplified summary of the additional information provided:

- The transfer function was not included to avoid ambiguity between transferring owned tokens and transferring authorized tokens.
- Specifying the current owner (`_from` parameter) is necessary for security reasons, particularly to prevent **front-running attacks**.

By requiring the `_from` parameter, the function ensures no ambiguity between **transferring an NFT you own** and **one you are authorized to transfer**, making the process more secure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @AdamBoudj! There's really 1 reason I see in your post, however - the cross-standard consistency. The simplification of the Developers' Experience is just a side-effect of the former. :P

Comment: In any case, if this turns out to be the only motivation for including/keeping the `_from` argument, I'll be quite disappointed, honestly... The amount of confusion and the inefficiency it causes far outweighs the argument of making the developer's life a little easier, imo. Besides, ERC-20 and ERC-721 are fundamentally different tokens - and so, it'd be logical to expect the developers to view them from different perspectives.

Comment: It's intriguing to consider how addressing this issue during EIP-721 development could have led to more efficient solutions. 

Introducing a new `transfer` function, similar to the one from ERC20, could be a non-breaking change that optimizes and simplifies the implementation. 

Striking a balance between simplicity and efficiency is vital, and your insights could maybe contribute to refining actual or future token standards.

Comment: The interface does not mandate an implementation. If the implementation does not leverage the gas saving when using the `_from` parameter, it's a fault of that specific implementation, not of the interface.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone even if the interface doesn't require a specific implementation, including the `_from` parameter influences how implementations are designed, it might not be a fault of the interface itself, but it does encourage a certain approach.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. This is the reason why developers should leverage that parameter, because otherwise, correctly, other developers raise questions about the reasons for that parameter in the first place. And as you already noted, OpenZeppelin's implementation calls `ownerOf` three times, which is very inefficient, so for me, it's not a good example for implementing that standard.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, as far as I can understand, you're suggesting not calling `ownerOf()`, at all. However, without doing this, we can only make sure that the `msg.sender` is allowed to transfer the NFTs of `_from` - and not that `_from` is the actual owner of the `_tokenId` NFT. Can't you see the danger of blindly believing the `transferFrom()` caller that the `_from` address they've submitted is, indeed, the rightful owner of the NFT that they want to transfer?

Comment: I'm not suggesting not checking ownership at all, but doing it when needed. In pseudo-code: "if msg.sender != _from check allowance; otherwise check ownership". [meta-note: to avoid duplicated messages, I put more details in the comments on the other response]

Comment: @AdamBoudj, the reasoning in your answer seems to be the best one we've got on the subject of this question. Therefore, I've just awarded you the bounty and made your answer the accepted one. Thank you!

Comment: @Iaroslav I appreciate it ! thanks 

Comment: @Iaroslav I've just updated my answer with additional information

Comment: @AdamBoudj, thanks for the extra information!
I have asked William for an example of a front-running attack in the case of not requiring `_from` when transferring NFTs. Can you think of any?..

Comment: @AdamBoudj, As to the argument of avoiding "ambiguity between transferring an NFT you own and one you are authorized to transfer", it doesn't convince me, at all... Why force everyone go the gas-inefficient way and include the `_from` argument for the sake of those contracts that might confuse transferring their tokens from transferring the tokens they have an allowance for? If you're calling the API, it's your job to understand it, after all...

Comment: @Iaroslav I agree with you, I hope he'll answer to your message and provide more information 

Answer (score 0):

I belive, it's for providing an additional safety net for `operators`.

[Operators](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification) (aka. `isApprovedForAll`) are addresses who are automatically approved for all NFTs of another address (whereas approvals are only for specific NFTs).

Imagine the following use case where we don't need to supply `_from`):

- Theoretical function signature: `function transfer(address to, uint256 tokenId) { ... }`
- You write a smart contract that acts as a market place.
- To make it easy for your users, therefore your contract is set as their operator.
- You only allow transfers between your users.

Now User `0xA` wants to transfer to user `0xB` and you proceed with the transaction because it's valid. (User `0xA` owns the NFT it wants to sell to `0xB`)

So far so good (the transaction is successful), however, since youre smart contract still has approval of the NFT (since it's an operator for both users), `0xA` could exploit you now. Note that `0xA` does not own the NFT anymore, but now `0xA` just sells the same NFT to `0xC`. **This would succeed even though it shouldn't**, because your contract is still the operator of both addresses and therefore allowed to do this transaction.

Now, if you provide as the `_from` argument always the `msg.sender` of your selling user, the transaction would fail the second time, since `0xA` is not the owner anymore (`0xB` is).

In the end it comes all down to design and personal preference... You would have to do an additonal check in your own smart contract to prevent this issue and you are right: In a lot of cases you don't need that behaviour but it is really useful once you have a smart contract functioning as an operator for multiple NFT holders.

Comment: Your example doesn't sound quite right, but let's try diving into it...

How exactly would `0xA` sell the NFT that has previously been transferred to `0xB`?
Given that the blockchain txs are atomic and unparralel, after the transfer from `0xA` to `0xB`, `0xA` would no longer be the owner of the NFT - and, therefore, wouldn't be able to do anything with it (including, selling it to `0xC`). The latter is so not because of the "market place" contract from your example, but because the contract of the NFT collection itself wouldn't allow this (if it's implemented correctly, of course).

Comment: It should still work out... Your contract (SC) has full access of all NFTs of your ERC-721 implementation for 0xA & 0xB. When the NFT gets transferred, to 0xB, SC can still transfer it, now if no additional safety checks are provided in SC, SC would try to transfer the NFT as invoked by 0xA, and since SC is also the operator of 0xB it would succeed. Everything can be avoided by putting a check in SC, but as I said it’s a precaution to give operator SCs as little room for failure as possible. Making the sender explicit will prevent a lot of vulnerabilities in scenarios like this.

Comment: requiring the address interacting with an NFT through your contract to actually be allowed to do anything with the NFT (by being either the owner or the approved operator for it) is essential for the correct functioning of your contract. Just like the NFT Collection contract must make sure the tx signer is allowed to interact with the NFTs from the Collection, your marketplace contract must also care about this. Making sure the `msg.sender` is allowed to act on an NFT can be checked independently of the passed `_from` argument, and, therefore, `_from` is not needed, IMO...

Comment: Yes I agree, "in the end it comes all down to personal preference". The standard decided to do it the explicit way and always makes sure that the sender knows exactly which transfer it is doing. Regarding unnecessary gas consumption I think this is [negligible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737409/solidity-how-does-function-parameters-size-affects-gas-cost) however, I would also be interested to see how it added up over time.

Answer (score 0):

If we stick with the standard interface, **one of the reasons is to save gas**.

Saving gas is always important, but especially for functions like `transfer` and `transferFrom`, which will likely be the most used functions of the contract.

If you don't specify a `_from` parameter, the smart contract must - as you said - always find the owner and then likely check for the allowance. If you specify the `_from` parameter, checking only for the allowance is enough in most cases because only the owner can have previously set that allowance.

And because reading from a ĐApp in Ethereum is a free operation, and on the contrary, it's always a paid operation from a smart contract, it's cheaper if it's the ĐApp takes care of calling the `ownerOf` function and then passing that value in the `_from` parameter.

[Here](https://github.com/InternetOfPeers/erc721) is a fast implementation of the `transferFrom` function leveraging the `_from` parameter to save gas. I started from the first reference implementation cited by the EIP-721 (the 0xcert's one, now [@nibbstack's one](https://github.com/nibbstack/erc721)), and in this specific case, you save ~950 GAS (max, ~610 average). You will see a much more considerable saving if you come from OpenZeppelin's implementation. This is just a fast example, and it can be improved more with enough time and patience.

Side note: technically, the `ownerOf` function described in the standard is `external`; therefore, it's meant to be called from a ĐApp and the other functions of the same contract cannot call it. With a typical implementation, the rest of the functions would have likely read the ownership of a token accessing a corresponding mapping variable inside the contract.

Comment: This is not true. `ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);` is actually called within `transferFrom` itself when the internal function `_isApprovedOrOwner` is used. 

And the funny thing, is that ownerOf is called **three times** per `transferFrom`.

Comment: I agree with @AdamBoudj: figuring out the actual owner of the NFT inside the `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions is essential for being able to properly verify whether the caller is, actually, allowed to perform the action on the NFT.

Comment: I don't know the implementation you are referring to, but the interface does not dictate the implementation. The reason to have the `_from` parameter is to save gas, if who implement the interface does not leverage it that is another story ;)

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, fair enough: we shouldn't be talking about specific implementations here, but, rather, about the original standard. However, if `ownerOf()` wouldn't be called inside the `transferFrom()` implementation, how could you make sure the tx creator is allowed to transfer the respective NFT?

Comment: I'm not suggesting not checking ownership at all, but doing it when needed, and here the `_from` parameter comes to help.  In pseudo-code, it is: "if msg.sender != `_from` check allowance; otherwise check ownership". If I have the allowance, the ownership is not relevant. And because the owner rarely uses the `transferFrom` function - they can use the `transfer` function for that - in the long run, the gas saving is tangible.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, imagine that I'm calling the function like this: `transferFrom( {_from: addrA, _to: addrB, _tokenId:1} )`. I may very well be an allowed operator for all of the NFTs owned by `addrA`, but this doesn't mean that the NFT with `_tokenId` == 1 is also owned by `addrA`. Unless the check of the latter is also enforced, I could just call `transferFrom()` on any NFT from the collection, passing the `addrA` as the `_from` in all of the calls... voilà le hack! :D

Comment: Mmm... I disagree :) You imply a hackable implementation of ApprovalForAll, to use it like a _jolly_ for doing whatever you want. It's not the case for - what I consider - a correct implementation, where allowance grants the ability to move a token, regardless of the ownership of the token, because that ownership is checked when the allowance is assigned, and regardless of the function you use for setting the allowance, even ApprovalForAll. If you imply a faulty ApprovalForAll, then you can hack the contract, but the same reasoning is valid for every functions you implement in a faulty manner.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, the implementation you suggest for NFT allowances is against the ERC-721 standard which explicitly states that "At the time of any transfer, the approved address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none".

Comment: I don't get why, unless you imply a faulty implementation from the beginning. I can leverage the _from parameter, I can do everything another implementation does plus more, not less. I can reset the allowance for that NFT after a transfer, as others do. If you are referring to an implementation where ApproveForAll is a general flag - but again, it's up to the specific implementation - you will have to deal with a deny list, and I don't personally suggest to go there, I prefer an allowance list for example. I'll try to find some time to write an implementation to showcase all these stuff.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, given how sure you seem to be about your idea, even though it hasn't been very popular in this thread of discussion (no offense :P), I'd be very curious to see it implemented! So, go ahead with it when you find the time, please! Also, note that I am not notified about your replies unless you tag me (with "@") explicitly...

Comment: @Iaroslav No offense at all, don't worry, discussions and different points of view are always welcome. Here is a fast implementation of the `transferFrom` function leveraging the `_from` parameter to save gas (https://github.com/InternetOfPeers/erc721). I started from the first reference implementation cited by the EIP-721 (the 0xcert's one, now @nibbstack's one), and in this specific case, you save ~950 GAS (max, ~610 average). You will see a much more considerable saving if you come from OZ implementation. And this is a fast example, and it can be improved more with enough time and patience.