# Attack vector in direct transfer function in EC721

Tags: erc-721, transfer, function

How the attack vector would look like in case of direct transfer function in EC721 standard. It is described in the [comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126708/why-erc721-does-not-have-direct-transfer-function,)

> A marketplace is transferring an NFT from Bob to Mary (among many
> other "legs" of a transaction). However, immediately before this leg,
> Bob sells that asset to Steve. Result: Bob is paid for sale to Steve
> and sale to Mary, but only Mary gets the asset.

but I still don't understand how is possible for attacker to bypass the owner check and sell NFT two times.